# block application started at reboot on raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry-pi 2 W for a project; it's a python application.
The application is a GUI with infinite loop that reads a GPIO and....works with that data... no matter of what the application does
By .bashrc, the compiled file starts and all works as expected.
The problem is that application cannot be blocked/killed/something

CTRL-C or any other keyboard combination don't work.
I tried to unplug the SD card from Raspberry and browse it by PC (windows based) and clearly I can't find ".bashrc" file
How could I restart using my raspberry again?
I would like modifying my application so upgrade it but I haven't found any way; I hope no format/reinstall is needed...not before have gotten the source code of my application

Comment: After several tests, I used a file to ready Linux files from Windows and I rewrote the image on SD-card.